# Maven Set up "Library not available" error in AnyPoint studio

Tags: eclipse, maven, maven-plugin, anypoint-studio, mulesoft

I'm trying to install maven in Anypoint Studio I have followed all the steps in  [How to Configure Maven With Mule AnyPoint Studio](https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-configure-maven-with-mule-anypoint-studio).

After all the steps I can see the JAR files are not getting downloaded into the `.m2` repository created in user file hence following error saying:

Error in libraries build path:

[image: Error in libraries build path]]

[image: error throwing in the console]]

I'm not sure what i'm missing here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added Profile to the settings.xml [Please refer this link to know how to add profile](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/3.9/maven-tools-for-mule-esb#adding-the-plugin-to-maven)

After that my issue is resolved